# Make a new list from three lists elements in a specific element order

Tags: java, algorithm, list

Say I have three lists:

```
 a = {a, b, c, d, e}  
 b = {A, B, C}  
 c = {aa, bb, cc, dd}
```

Now I need to take 3 elements from each list and insert them into a new list, from list a to c. So the new list should be:

```
newlist = {a, b, c, A, B, C, aa, bb, cc, d, e, dd}
```

I'm wondering what's the fastest way to do this in Java?

[update]
unify datatypes to make the requirement more clear.

Comment: Do elements in the first list have to be the lists themselves? (a=a, b=b, c=c)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Iterables.concat(Iterable<T> ...)`, it creates a live view of all the iterables, concatenated into one (if you change the iterables, the concatenated version also changes). Then wrap the concatenated iterable with `Iterables.unmodifiableIterable(Iterable<T>)` (I hadn't seen the read-only requirement earlier).

From the `Iterables.concat( .. )` JavaDocs:

Combines multiple iterables into a single iterable. The returned iterable has an iterator that traverses the elements of each iterable in inputs. The input iterators are not polled until necessary. The returned iterable's iterator supports remove() when the corresponding input iterator supports it.

While this doesn't explicitly say that this is a live view, the last sentence implies that it is (supporting the `Iterator.remove()` method only if the backing iterator supports it is not possible unless using a live view)

Sample Code:

```
final List<Integer> first  = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3);
final List<Integer> second = Lists.newArrayList(4, 5, 6);
final List<Integer> third  = Lists.newArrayList(7, 8, 9);
final Iterable<Integer> all =
    Iterables.unmodifiableIterable(
        Iterables.concat(first, second, third));
System.out.println(all);
third.add(9999999);
System.out.println(all);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 999, 9999]
```

After getting the result you can sort the single list.

Merge sort is really quite easy.

```
/**
 * Mergesort algorithm.
 * @param a an array of Comparable items.
 */
public static void mergeSort( Comparable [ ] a ) {
    Comparable [ ] tmpArray = new Comparable[ a.length ];
    mergeSort( a, tmpArray, 0, a.length - 1 );
}

/**
 * Internal method that makes recursive calls.
 * @param a an array of Comparable items.
 * @param tmpArray an array to place the merged result.
 * @param left the left-most index of the subarray.
 * @param right the right-most index of the subarray.
 */
private static void mergeSort( Comparable [ ] a, Comparable [ ] tmpArray,
        int left, int right ) {
    if( left < right ) {
        int center = ( left + right ) / 2;
        mergeSort( a, tmpArray, left, center );
        mergeSort( a, tmpArray, center + 1, right );
        merge( a, tmpArray, left, center + 1, right );
    }
}

/**
 * Internal method that merges two sorted halves of a subarray.
 * @param a an array of Comparable items.
 * @param tmpArray an array to place the merged result.
 * @param leftPos the left-most index of the subarray.
 * @param rightPos the index of the start of the second half.
 * @param rightEnd the right-most index of the subarray.
 */
private static void merge( Comparable [ ] a, Comparable [ ] tmpArray,
        int leftPos, int rightPos, int rightEnd ) {
    int leftEnd = rightPos - 1;
    int tmpPos = leftPos;
    int numElements = rightEnd - leftPos + 1;

    // Main loop
    while( leftPos <= leftEnd && rightPos <= rightEnd )
        if( a[ leftPos ].compareTo( a[ rightPos ] ) <= 0 )
            tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ leftPos++ ];
        else
            tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ rightPos++ ];

    while( leftPos <= leftEnd )    // Copy rest of first half
        tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ leftPos++ ];

    while( rightPos <= rightEnd )  // Copy rest of right half
        tmpArray[ tmpPos++ ] = a[ rightPos++ ];

    // Copy tmpArray back
    for( int i = 0; i < numElements; i++, rightEnd-- )
        a[ rightEnd ] = tmpArray[ rightEnd ];
}
```

Comment: I think OPs intentions are different. list `a` is integer and list `b` and `c` are char types. Atlest they look look like chars types.

Comment: My intention was to give idea, not exact answer. let him go and do some more coding ..